# OpenGL: Drawing lines with varying width

Tags: graphics, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am looking for a way to draw 3D lines with varying width. I know that i can create triangles, as in the following tutorial: http://www.merowing.info/2012/04/drawing-smooth-lines-with-cocos2d-ios-inspired-by-paper/#.U1OZeea28rf

However, it will not look good in 3D when camera is rotated. Is there a good way to draw 3D lines with varying width?

Comment: it's unclear what you're after. how should they vary in width, notably when it rotates?

Comment: For example, i want part of the line to be with width=2 and part with width=5, etc.

Comment: Why does it not look good when the camera is rotated, what is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If you think that it'll not look good in 3D, because when looking at it edge-on, the line will fade out, then the line should be drawn as an actual 3d object, with a `z`. Then it is no longer a line, but a cylinder or cuboid or whatever geometry you choose to use.

There's no in-built method in open-gl to draw lines with varying thickness. You have to do it yourself, or use an external library.

Found [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/199525/Drawing-nearly-perfect-D-line-segments-in-OpenGL), when I searched for it.